# KDTele in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I wrote a answer machine with KDTele. 
It works well in xp without any problem, but it has some problem in windows 7.
when someone call my answer machine, it should play a recorded message, but in windows 7 the caller can not hear any sound. I can record the caller voice but the caller can not hear my answer machine's recorded voice.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your modem driver. Some modems' voice does not work properly on Win 7. Especially modems with the conexant chipset.